# How to show Sum of Two fields in Grid in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento

I am working on a extension in which user enter different price for " Stamp Cost, Ink Cost, 
Form Cost ". currently in data grid i am showing value of one field

```
$this->addColumn('stamp_cost', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('imprint')->__('Stamp Cost'),
    'width'     => '100px',
    'type'  => 'price',
    'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
    'index'     => 'stamp_cost'
));
```

But Now I Need to show sum of all these fields in one column

How can we show sum of two fields in one column in magento admin data grid  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, there are two ways to do it. Add the field to the collection and get the data from the database, or calculate it in PHP based on the 3 values returned from the DB. Doing the first way with the Magento Collection would, in my opinion, be too complex. instead, you want to use a Renderer (`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract`)

First, inside of the `Block/Adminhtml` folder of your plugin, make a new folder called Renderer. Inside of it make a new file called `CostSum.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php 
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_CostSum extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
         return $row->getStampCost() + $row->getInkCost() + $row->getFormCost();
    }
}
```

Then, in the grid, make a new column

```
$this->addColumn('cost_total', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('imprint')->__('Stamp Cost'),
    //'index'     => 'Im not sure this is necessary',
    'type'      => 'price',
    'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
    'renderer' => new Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_CostSum() 
));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The more right way is `'renderer'  => 'company_module/adminhtml_renderer_costSum'`.

Comment: Thanks @Max for providing great solution. I have followed the same steps but it just giving me fatal error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function setColumn() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\mage\imprint\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column.php on line 291`

Comment: After some google, I have little bit modified your code  'renderer' => new Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_CostSum() and now its working fine. Many Thanks again @Max

Comment: Using this way the last total column wont show the total values on grid, only show $0, because using render, how can we do a sum to show totals at bottom?

Answer (score 0):

> The more right way is 'renderer' => 'company_module/adminhtml_renderer_costSum'

As @Zyava says, the correct option is this. But actually, is not 'company_module'. Instead you should call it as you have declared your blocks in the config.xml file.

```
<blocks>
    <declaration>
        <class>Company_Module_Block</class>
    </declaration>
</blocks>
```

So, in this case you should create the 'renderer' as:

'renderer' => 'declaration/adminhtml_renderer_costSum'